# File upload field not working inside a web view in android

Tags: android, file-upload, laravel-5, webview, android-5.0-lollipop

I have a webapplication made in Laravel Framework. I am launching it inside the web view of an android application. All works well but when i press the **choose file** It does no work. Its completely inactive. How to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

I think you make use of the [input attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp) in your html, don't you?
As written [here](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview) (FAQ part) it does not work out-of-the-box in webviews by now.
Maybe you can give the [WebChromeClient.onShowFileChooser](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onShowFileChooser(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.ValueCallback%3Candroid.net.Uri[]%3E,%20android.webkit.WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams)) a shot (added API 21).

Comment: Alex D thanks for your answer. yes i used input attribute in my html.. I will be using WebChromeClient.onShowFileChooser as per ur suggestion.. will revert if all goes fine.